# How to call a custom dialog fragment from a RecyclerViewAdapter inside a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to call a custom dialog fragment i have created from a dialog fragment adapter that extends a recyclerView. I'm using the latest android studio with androidx. the following code is for the Custom dialog Adapter

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import tino.varconn.com.instantecocash.R;

public class DialogSendMoneyFirst extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send_money_first, container, false);

    // Do all the stuff to initialize your custom view

    return v;
}
```

The following code i am trying to use to call the dialog fragment

```
package tino.varconn.com.instantecocash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import tino.varconn.com.instantecocash.dialogs.DialogSendMoneyFirst;

public class EcocashAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<EcocashAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<EcocashModel> itemList;
Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView img;
    public CardView cardView;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }
}


public EcocashAdapter(List<EcocashModel> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}



@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    EcocashModel ecocashModel = itemList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(ecocashModel.getName());
    holder.img.setImageResource(ecocashModel.getImage());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == 0){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Send Money", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DialogSendMoneyFirst dialog = new DialogSendMoneyFirst();
                dialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");

            }
            if (position == 1){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pay Merchant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
```

And this is the error :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentManagerandroidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.getFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Your `context` is `null`. How do you pass `context` to `adapter`? Can you add more details about your adapter?

Comment: I dont know how to pass, i just declared the context as : Context context

Comment: I think it's a bad design to open dialogs inside the Adapter. you should probably call up to the Activity or Fragment to execute the show of the Fragment Dialog. Use interfaces/callbacks to propagate the click to the main view components that holds the adapter, and there you have the context already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_list_row, parent, false);
    context = itemView.getContext()
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

If not work :

1.Check your activity is AppCompact or not.

2.If you are calling your adapter from fragment then use getChildFragmentManager()

3. If you are calling your adapter from Activity then use getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Can you please tell me from where you calling this "DialogSendMoneyFirst dialog = new DialogSendMoneyFirst();
dialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog"); "

Comment: Don't use all together, try one by one

Comment: As you are using AndroidX then you need use number one option, its mandatory. And try other three with that.

Comment: You didn't initialize the context and you are using it.

 let me edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `context` is `null`

Try this:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

instead of:

```
(AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your context arrives from Fragment, then you have to use below: [cast context to FragmentActivity]

```
dialog.show(((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
```